# Getting "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" in Python 3.8.3

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I am trying to perform [Winsorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing) to handle outliers in my data in a traditional way without using any libraries like [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html), etc. Below is my code & the variables used in the code are explained in the below picture for reference. I am coming across an error ***TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed*** when executing the below code. Can you please advise how I can solve this? Thank you in Advance!

**What I am trying to achieve**: To remove outliers by moving them within upper and lower boundaries. I can also choose to omit them but they contain useful info that could help my ML model, so I am compelled to use the Winsorization method.

[image: Box Plot]

```
for i in num_data.columns:
    q1=num_data[i].quantile(0.25)
    q3=num_data[i].quantile(0.75)
    iqr=q3-q1
    ub=q3 + 1.5*iqr
    lb=q1 - 1.5*iqr

    num_data[i]=num_data[i].replace({num_data[num_data[i]>ub][i]: num_data[i].quantile(0.99)})
    num_data[i]=num_data[i].replace({num_data[num_data[i]<lb][i]: num_data[i].quantile(0.01)})
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-f569ef8070aa> in <module>
      6     lb=q1 - 1.5*iqr
      7 
----> 8     num_data[i]=num_data[i].replace({num_data[num_data[i]>ub][i]: num_data[i].quantile(0.99)})
      9     num_data[i]=num_data[i].replace({num_data[num_data[i]<lb][i]: num_data[i].quantile(0.01)})

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __hash__(self)
   1664     def __hash__(self):
   1665         raise TypeError(
-> 1666             f"{repr(type(self).__name__)} objects are mutable, "
   1667             f"thus they cannot be hashed"
   1668         )

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```